# Make an object rotate according to mouse movement. [UNITY C#]

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, quaternions

I’m starting a learning project. The idea is that you have an archer character that is static, that has a bow attached to it that shoots arrows to targets of varying difficulty.
Turns out that right at the start I’m stuck. How do I make it so that the bow rotates when the player clicks and holds the mouse anywhere on the screen? So I click+hold and move left/right and the bow rotates left/right to aim the shot. I’d like to also eventually make it portable to phones (so you’d tap+hold etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow isnt a code writing service but i will explain what you must do:

### Method 1 (Exact Aiming):

For every frame the mouse is down:

1. Make a `Ray` from a screen point... hint (use
   `camera.ScreenPointToRay`).
2. Get a far point along the `Ray` using `ray.GetPoint(distance);`.
3. `Bow.Transform.LookAt(newPoint, Vector3.Up);`.

### Method 2 (Continuous Movement):

1. Make a variable `oldMousePos` to store a `Vector2` location.
2. Record your initial screen click position into that variable on a
   mouse down event.
3. Have a function that runs once every frame the mouse *stays* down.
4. For the direction of the rotation of the bow, you can use
   `(newMousePos - oldMousePos).normalized;`.
5. For the speed of rotation for your bow, you can use `(newMousePos -
   oldMousePos).sqrMagnitude;`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer sorry it took so long Im just sort of new to the site and forgot to select it. I appreciate you trying to make me think and not giving me the whole thing straight up.